# Power BI and Insightly

Tags: powerbi, insightly

I connected to Insightly from Power BI (Power BI service) to use Microsoft created default reports.  It's the first time that I use power BI service and I figured out some capabilities of Power BI desktop don't exist there (e.g. add conditional column).

Fetched data is dirty in some cases and I need to clean the data. This is a small project and I am not going to fetch Insightly data into database and clean data there. I just need to show corrected data in Power BI. Imagine following scenario: 'location of some records are set to 'Mel,Australia' instead of 'Melbourne, Australia', Hence count of records for Melbourne is not correct and I need to change 'Mel' into 'Melbourne''.

I know how to do that in desktop version but I don't have any idea how I can do that in Power BI service with limited transform capabilities. I appreciate if someone could help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an actual limitation, you can upvote on the insightly site.

[Insightly-feed-Data-Pack-for-Power-BI-desktop-version](https://support.insight.ly/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000635807-please-create-Insightly-feed-Data-Pack-for-Power-BI-desktop-version)

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with your Power BI Desktop reports then when you Publish to the service the Queries you've developed to clean the data will also be uploaded to the service. When the dataset in the service refreshes the data cleansing will happen each time.

Comment: I wanna use out-of-box reports created on PowerBI service. Hence, I have to export data from powerBI service into desktop, develop it and publish it again and do that for all of reports that I wanna change! It's impossible regarding increasing number of reports